# Strange error in ios -- Array.from(...) crashes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I had a maddening error in my web app where it would not load properly ONLY on an iOS ipad (ver 8.3) -- running either Chrome or Safari.  It would not accept the code:

```
x = Array.from([0,1,2]);
```

I just coded around this, using "new Array(...)".  But is this a known issue, or am I experiencing something strange?  My googling did not reveal any insight on this issue.

EDIT: For future travelers, "a = new Array(b)" was also giving me weird results.  The following works:  "a = b.slice()"

Comment: I guess those browsers don't support `from`. use [MDN polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill) or `new Array` or `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Which ios? I am here on 9.2 and it seems to work.

Comment: Running version 8.3.

Comment: According to es6 compatibility list, array static methods were added in 9.x.